# How to check if user is logged in without request.session

Tags: javascript, express, session

I am implementing a web application using **Express** and **Docker**. I am also using a **Three layered architecture**. When a user logs in, I store that information in a session. I have blogposts as a resource in my app. To retrieve the blogpostId I will send a query to the database in the **Data access layer** like this:

```
const db = require('./db')

exports.getBlogpostId = function(id ,callback){

    const query = "SELECT * FROM blogposts WHERE blogId = ?"
    const value = [id]
    db.query(query, value, function(error, blogpost){
        if(error){
            callback("DatabaseError", null)
        }else{
            callback(null, blogpost)
        }
    })
}
```

Now in my **Business logic layer** I want to check if the user is logged in or not, something like this:

```
const blogRepo = require('../dal/blog-repository')


exports.getBlogpostId = function(id){

    if(/*If the user is logged in*/){
        return blogRepo.getBlogpostId(id)
    }else{
        throw "Unauthorized!"
    }
}
```

How can I check if they are logged in here. How can I get the session that I stored when they logged in?

Thanks!

Comment: So, the business layer doesn't generically know anything about the logged in state at all.  It's business logic, not web logic.  If you want it to have access to state like that, you have to pass that state into it as arguments any time you call it.  You can either decide that it's OK for the business logic to see the session object and pass the whole session object into it or you need to pass the specific pieces of the session object that the business logic needs such as the authentication state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the business layer doesn't generically know anything about the logged in state at all. It's business logic, not web logic.

If you want it to have access to state like that, you have to pass that state into it as arguments any time you call it.

You can either decide that it's OK for the business logic to see the session object and pass the whole session object into it or you need to pass the specific pieces of the session object that the business logic needs such as the authentication state.